# модификаторы доступа в интерфейсах

Tags: java, java-8

Можно ли задавать методам интерфейса модификатор private или protected? Если да то зачем?

Answer (score 3):

Начиная с Java 8 интерфейсы стали поддерживать реализации методов по умолчанию, а так же статические методы. В Java 9 была добавлена поддержка приватных `private` и приватных статических `private static` методов, которые могут вызываться из реализаций методов по умолчанию и из статических методов внутри интерфейсов соответственно. Методы с доступом `protected` и `default` интерфейсами не поддерживаются. Всё таки интерфейсы должны оставаться интерфейсами.

Пример использования `private` и `private static` методов в интерфейсе:

```
public interface MyInterface {

    // начиная с Java 8
    default String getName() {
        return getClass().getName() + " at " + getDate();
    }

    // начиная с Java 9
    private String getDate() {
        return new Date().toString();
    }

    // начиная с Java 8
    static String getStaticName() {
        return MyInterface.class.getName() + " at " + getStaticDate();
    }

    // начиная с Java 9
    private static String getStaticDate() {
        return new Date().toString();
    }
}

public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    //
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        System.out.println(myClass.getName());

        System.out.println(MyInterface.getStaticName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно с Java 9.
[Сравнение 7, 8 и 9 жавы](https://www.journaldev.com/12850/java-9-private-methods-interfaces)